# remove item selected by the user from a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a contact managers program in a console application using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have a method to create a contact and a contact object. I also have a method to delete a contact but I want to have the user to be able to pick a contact name and be able to delete the selected contact. However I am unsure how to do this.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            //Declare the list

            List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

            //Main Driver
            char menuItem;
             Console.WriteLine("Contact List\n");
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            while (menuItem != 'Q')
            {

                ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, contactList);
                menuItem = GetMenuItem();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
        static char GetMenuItem()
        {
            char menuItem;
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nPlease pick an item: "));
            while (menuItem != 'C'
                && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'Q' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D' && menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'F' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'T')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
                DisplayMenu();
                menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nEnter option or M for menu:"));
            }
            return menuItem;
        }

        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
           Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
           Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
           Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
           Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
           Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
           Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
           Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
           Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
           Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
        }

        //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
        static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, List<Contact> contactList)
        {
            switch (menuItem)
            {
                case 'C':
                    createContact();
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    removeContact(contactList);
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    updateContact(contactList);
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    LoadFromFile();
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    saveToFile();
                    break;

                case 'L':
                    sortByLastName(contactList);
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    sortByFirstName(contactList);
                       break;
                case 'P':
                       DisplayList(contactList);
                       break;
                case 'T':
                       sortByContactType();
                       break;
                case 'Q':

                       break;

            }                   
        }
//allows the user to remove a contact
         public static void removeContact(List<Contact> contactList) 
         {

             for (int i = 0; i < contactList.Count; i++)
               if (i % 5 == 0)
             contactList.RemoveAt(i);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function like this: which will accept the `List` and a `contact name` then it will delete the first occurrence of the contact name from the contact list.

```
 public static void removeContact(List<Contact> contactList, object ContactName)
        {
            Contact contactToRemove = (Contact)contactList.AsEnumerable().Where
                                      (x => x.ContactName == ContactName || 
                                       x.ContactNumber == (int)ContactName).First();
            contactList.Remove(contactToRemove);
        }
```

my contact class is:

```
  class Contact
    {
        private int _ContactNumber;

        public int ContactNumber
        {
            get { return _ContactNumber; }
            set { _ContactNumber = value; }
        }
        private string  _ContactName;

        public string  ContactName
        {
            get { return _ContactName; }
            set { _ContactName = value; }
        }              
   }
```

So your case will be something like this:

```
 case 'R':
         Console.WriteLine("enter the contact name/Contact Number To delete");
         removeContact(contactList, Console.Read().ToString() );
         break;
```

Comment: In this a contact name could be same ,You should select a Unique field which cannot match ,Use the Phone number instead that would have been better

Comment: @ vishal : i had updated my answer now it is capable of removing details based on contact name or contact number

Comment: But a contact should never be deleted using contact name !! , as a name could be repeated there can be two person with same name!!  , And appreciate you updated it still you should always remove or edit something which is unique , I would say use number itself or Id if it has

Comment: @vishal: you are correct. thanks for the suggestion. your answer is also great. i support you.

Answer (score 4):

**You can do it easily using LINQ or Lambda Expression:**

In the Model Class of the Contact make a field say the Phone Number itself.

While selecting the contact two parameters in the

```
removeContact(List<Contact> contactList,int selectedContactPhoneNo)
```

You can simply do then:

```
contactList.RemoveAll(x => x.PhoneNo == selectedContactPhoneNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to loop over the contact list and then use one of the property from your contact as search key.

```
//Search contact via number
//Depending which key you would want for example Contact's Number:
int number = 1;
Contact contact = null;
for (int i = 0; i < contactList.Count; i++)
{
    if (contactList[i].Number == number)
    {
        contact = contactList[i]; //Assign contact 
        break;
    }
}

//Remove contact from list
if (contact != null) //If not null, it means we found it. Remove it from the list:
{
    contactList.Remove(contact);
}
```

You can create a function for the above implementation to pass the specific keyword when searching and removing item from your list.